# Mounting docker volume on specific path

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to deploy photo-stream (https://github.com/maxvoltar/photo-stream) using a docker container. Photo-stream is a picture publishing site meant for self-hosting. It expects its pictures in a path called 'photos/original/', relative to where it's installed. It will create other directories under 'photos/' to cache thumbnails and such.

When I populate that directory with some pictures and start the application natively (without docker) from its build directory using:

`$ bundle exec jekyll serve --host 0.0.0.0`

it shows me the pictures I put in that directory. When running the application inside a docker container, I need it to
mount a volume that contains a path 'photos/original' so that I can keep my pictures there. I have created this path on
a disk mounted at /mnt/data/.

In order to do that, I have added a volume line to the existing Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:latest
ENV VIPSVER 8.9.1
RUN apt update && apt -y upgrade && apt install -y build-essential
RUN wget -O ./vips-$VIPSVER.tar.gz https://github.com/libvips/libvips/releases/download/v$VIPSVER/vips-$VIPSVER.tar.gz
RUN tar -xvzf ./vips-$VIPSVER.tar.gz && cd vips-$VIPSVER && ./configure && make && make install
COPY ./ /photo-stream 
WORKDIR /photo-stream
RUN ruby -v && gem install bundler jekyll && bundle install
VOLUME /photo-stream/photos 
EXPOSE 4000
ENTRYPOINT bundle exec jekyll serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

I build the container this way:

```
$ docker build --tag photo-stream:1.0 .
```

I run the container this way:

```
$ docker run -d -p 4000:4000 -v /mnt/data/photos/:/photos/ --name ps photo-stream:1.0
```

I was expecting the content of the directory /mnt/data/photos to be shown. Instead, nothing is shown. However, a volume '/var/lib/docker/volumes/e5ff426ced2a5e786ced6b47b67d7dee59160c60f59f481516b638805b731902/_data' is created, and when that is populated with pictures, those are shown.

Comment: The second part of your `docker run -v` option is `/photos/`, in the root directory of the container; do you mean `/photo-stream/photos`?  (You do not need a Dockerfile `VOLUME` directive.)

Comment: @DavidMaze that makes sense, so I changed /photos/ to /photo-stream/photos/ but when I attach to the running container, /photos/ is still empty. Regardless of what photo-stream will be doing, I had at least expected my 'original'-directory to be there. Is the VOLUME directive in fact in the way?

Comment: The bind mount will hide anything that was in the image (if there was a `/photo-stream/photos/originals` but the host does not have a `/mnt/data/photos/originals` directory, the `originals` directory inside the container gets hidden).  I would not expect to see a `/photos` directory at all.  I'd recommend deleting `VOLUME` if you're not 100% clear on what it does.

Comment: Thanks, I have removed the directive so now all I'm doing is run the container with `-v /mnt/data/photos/:/photo-stream/photos/`, and when I inspect the running container, I can see my pictures. Thanks!